# How do I use the Queue library in SML/NJ

Tags: queue, sml, smlnj, ml

I see that the SML/NJ includes a queue structure. I can't figure out how to use it. How do I use the additional libraries provided by SML/NJ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`Queue` structure](http://www.smlnj.org/doc/smlnj-lib/Manual/queue.html) is not specified by SML '97, but it is present in SML/NJ's top-level environment.

```
$ sml
Standard ML of New Jersey v110.69 [built: Fri Mar 13 16:02:47 2009]
- Queue.mkQueue ();
[autoloading]
[library $SMLNJ-LIB/Util/smlnj-lib.cm is stable]
[autoloading done]
stdIn:1.1-1.17 Warning: type vars not generalized because of
   value restriction are instantiated to dummy types (X1,X2,...)
val it = - : ?.X1 Queue.queue
-
```

You can `open` a structure.  This lets you avoid typing `Queue.` in front of everything.  It's discouraged to do this at the top-level, though, because it pollutes the environment and makes it much less obvious what you're depending on.  (Within another structure I'd say it might be acceptable in some situations.)

```
$ sml
Standard ML of New Jersey v110.69 [built: Fri Mar 13 16:02:47 2009]
- open Queue;
[autoloading]
[library $SMLNJ-LIB/Util/smlnj-lib.cm is stable]
[autoloading done]
opening Queue
  type 'a queue
  exception Dequeue
  val mkQueue : unit -> 'a queue
  val clear : 'a queue -> unit
  val isEmpty : 'a queue -> bool
  val enqueue : 'a queue * 'a -> unit
  val dequeue : 'a queue -> 'a
  val next : 'a queue -> 'a option
  val delete : 'a queue * ('a -> bool) -> unit
  val head : 'a queue -> 'a
  val peek : 'a queue -> 'a option
  val length : 'a queue -> int
  val contents : 'a queue -> 'a list
  val app : ('a -> unit) -> 'a queue -> unit
  val map : ('a -> 'b) -> 'a queue -> 'b queue
  val foldl : ('a * 'b -> 'b) -> 'b -> 'a queue -> 'b
  val foldr : ('a * 'b -> 'b) -> 'b -> 'a queue -> 'b
- mkQueue ();
stdIn:3.1-3.11 Warning: type vars not generalized because of
   value restriction are instantiated to dummy types (X1,X2,...)
val it = - : ?.X1 queue
-
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a complete answer for you but I could point you in the right direction. You should look up using the compilation manager (CM) which is built in to SML/NJ. You can think of it as Make for SML.

To use a library from the SML/NJ library you then add smlnj-lib.cm to the CM description file of your application. Then you can use the declarations such as Queue from that library.

The smlnj website has some documentation about the [compilation manager](http://www.smlnj.org/doc/CM/index.html).

Hope this at least points you in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create an integer Queue, use the following code. Replace 'int' with the datatype you want.

```
val que = Queue.mkqueue(): int Queue.queue
```

Everything else can be found [here.](http://www.smlnj.org/doc/smlnj-lib/Manual/queue.html)